# Reading data from a tar.gz file with python

Tags: python, audio, encoding

I am trying to read data from [this](https://research.google.com/audioset/download.html) audio dataset that has it's JSON structured like the following:

```
context: {
  feature: {
    key  : "video_id"
    value: {
      bytes_list: {
        value: [YouTube video id string]
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "start_time_seconds"
    value: {
      float_list: {
        value: 6.0
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "end_time_seconds"
    value: {
      float_list: {
        value: 16.0
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "labels"
      value: {
        int64_list: {
          value: [1, 522, 11, 172] # The meaning of the labels can be found here.
        }
      }
    }
}
feature_lists: {
  feature_list: {
    key  : "audio_embedding"
    value: {
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [128 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [128 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
    }
    ... # Repeated for every second of the segment
  }

}
```

This is the intended structure of a 2.4 Gb `features.tar.gz` file. To extract this file, I'm using this code:

```
import tarfile
import numpy as np
import json

tar = tarfile.open("features.tar.gz")
len(tar.members) # returns 12,232
member = tar.extractfile(tar.members[100]).read() # content of the 100th member
print(member)
```

But looking at `member`, I see this huge bytes array instead of the JSON I would expect:

```
b'\xe4\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x87r\xe5d\nn\n\x1e\n\x12start_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x11\n\x06labels\x12\x07\x1a\x05\n\x03bce\n\x1c\n\x10end_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00 A\n\x1b\n\x08video_id\x12\x0f\n\r\n\x0bUUjPZPtqG5k\x12\xf1\n\n\xee\n\n\x0faudio_embedding\x12\xda\n\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01v<n=Dd\xab\x93\xed\x83\x8bn\x98\xb0{l\x9c\xa1=\xd5fd\xe3\xc8\x8d\x8a4u\xff[\x00\x8e\xac\x80\xedx\x00i\x83\x9a\xb3*-\xe0UE\x10\x9f\x9d\xbep\x07U7\xdc\xacX\xaf\'\x1ek;\xaaWF\x80\x17u\x95\x9ce\xff\x93\xff-\x12\x18\xf7\xff\x00\xdf\x00\xa5\xffj1\xa6\xa5\xff\xff\x81\xad\xff\x00\xff\x00\xabC\x00\xd6\x9b\xf3]\x00\xca\x00\x0c\xffh\x02\x82\xd2\xb8\xd1\x00\xd4\x004\xb2\xffZ\xb1\xff\x8a\xff\xa9\x00\x8f\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01[^\\3\x06B\xdf\x98\xff_I\x8ap\xc8\x8bc\xdc\xaa#\xff~D\xff\xea\x98\x99\x0fv\xff\x14\x00\x81\xf7\x8f\xdc\x8e\x00V\x90\xe0\x84\x00"\xf1,\x0e\x00\xa9\xea\xa5\xc8\x00D\x00\xb0\xff.\xdd\x00\x0e\x1ab\xa8W\x8b\x12\x00\x93\x00\xee_\xff\xad\xffQ\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\xf6O\xaf\xff\x90\xd4\xd0(\xff\xa3\xd5\xbd\xff\x00\xff\x19\x95\x00\x00\xff)\xea\x00\x00\xff\x00\x80\x97\x0f\x85\xf5\xff\xff\xc4\x00\xa79\x00-\xectF\xff\x86\xff(\x03J\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01mOwMFk\xcfi\xff\x96oW\xcc\xd9C]\x8e\x9bo\xe8d\x12\xd2\xa7\x90~L\xa6\xffO\x00\x00\xcbx\x8f\x8c\x00\xa2\x84\x94D\x00\x08\xff-6\x00\xa0\x9b\xff\x9e\x00\x9a\x1e\xcb\xb3,\xff\x00iY\x00\x941\xbe:>;\xb6\x88\x9b\xff\xa2\xffo\x00P\xf2\xff\x8c\xd3\x84\xfa\xff\xf1|\x91\xa6\xff\xffl\xff\xff6v8\xa2\x05\x00\xff}\x04\xa9\x17\xff\x00\x9a\xff\x18\x00\x00\xbe\x1db\x00\xc1\x86R\xcb\x9d\xeb\xac\xd9\xcd\xff=B\xb5\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x95F\x88F\x92>\x96t\xda\xae\xa5{\x92\xa4S:\x89Na\x9bg@\xc0gr\xbek\x99\xffy\t\x00\xc4T\x95t\x88\x85;"\xb61K\xb4`\x82I[\x7f\xd2_\xef21\xde\xd1O\xc3Yr\xc6\x19}0\xa3\x9cN\x0bzeu\xc4\xa5\xffC\x0fV\xee\xff\xbbr\x99\xe7\xda\x8ewf\xdd\x8cz\x8f\xce\xea\xa3Li7U>n\xc4mZ\x08\xd7\xa6\xbb\xb2\x94\x00\\\r\x00\xd1\xb2\x8c\x00\xc1\x8a\xad\xbe|\xff\xff\xba\x93e\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x908\x81?m]\x8e\x8d\xe3\x8c\x8e\x84}\xa9RR\x8d\x7ft\x83;u\xd5y\x8a\xa1\x94\xa3\xff\xae\x00I\x7f\x10\xb3\xc4D3\x9d^\x94B8\xf7Y\x97l\x80\xbf\xffQb\x9b\x1f\xf3}\xa1\xae?"\x82=\xa37h\x81i\t\xca\xc9N\xff\xbb\xee\x86\x00H\xff\xffh\xca<\xca\xff|\xae8]\xff\xff\x17\xfe\xfc6\xf1\x00\x7f#4`\xe8\xa1\x9fG\xfc\x83g\x9dn\x006\x7fr\xd2\x82\xff\x00\x8f\xc4\xffw\xff\xff\xa4\xff\x00\x03\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01Kaof\x14"\xc2*\xffz\x00_\x95\xd8\x1a\x830c\xa5\xfe\x8fe\xff\xa3\'\x96\'\x06\xff\x00\x00[\xb8\x98R\xcc\x00KO\xa5E}\x07\xff\x15j\x17\xf9\xf4\xffqc%\x03;\xe4Y\xff\x00(\xae\x85\xbf/E\x00\x00`\x00\xe5\xe8\xff\xff\xba\xae\x00\x83j\xffZ^\xff\x82\xff\x85\xbf\xdf\x8b\x00\x1b\xa4\xcbC\xb2\xe9p\xff\x1d\x92l\x00\xff\x00\xff\xd4V@\xde\x1es\x14\x00\xa6\xff\x1af\xc2uh\x01f\x00+\xc7\xff\x00\xc0\x00\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xacIwp\x8cypV\xfd\xb6FU\xac\xa3\x12AzK\xc5\x8cQ\x81\xc8\x01\xb5\xda\xb4D\xffU\x1e\x00Lhi\x95U5v%2k\r\xff\xc9d`\xd8f\xff\x81\xff\x15\x00(\xdf?\xb2\x02pv\x89Gp\x05uQPS\xd5m\x91\xff\xff6$\x9b:\x83\xff\x11\x83\x9f\xef\xbb\xa6nf\x00d/\xff\x93`t\x84\xb2f\xc3\'\xbe\x86i\xb7\xbe\xa2P\xa5.h\x00:pZ\x82j\x9d\xa0\x96k\xff.h\x9a\xd6p\xa0\x91\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01cH\xb5JJh\x91<\xffs6d\xdd\xc5\x04\x11N/\xbe\x9c,w\xfdiP\xbf[^\xff\x00\x00/\x99Q\xcd\x8f\x13S{\x009\x10@\xc8\x86M^\xe6_\xffj\xffb+\x91\xafB\xdf;\x1b\xd5\x87n1\x00&z{\xa8\xb0o\x88\xddP\x00\x00\xc4t\xebyw^\xd7\xaf\xffdQ\xb8n\x93@\xba\xe7vt]\xa4\xb7\xc0\xb2p\x93\xab\xc0\xa3\x97\xba\x9e,\x1d\x02&\x00\xff<kN\xda\xb8\x00y\x9b\x91\xd6\xf9\xff\xff\xe7\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01fE\x80#Fo\xa1\xa6\xe9\x92\x7f\x8c\x8a\xadL;\xb5\xa6>\xda|a\xed\xd0\x87\x9f\x1ac\xffj\x00s\xa5\x96\xb7V\x00D\x7f\xc7o:.o`F&Z\xb3\xde\x7f\x00T\x18\xcb\xb7#\xc7\x12\x0bqpV6`L\x00\x7fi\xa9N\xff\x9f\xffi\x00 \xff\xffG\xc3!\xef\xff\xa8\xd5{\x7f\xff\xec\x8d\xff\xff?\xff\x18\xa2\x11\x04\xd3v\x9a\x12\x05\xff\x003\xdc5\x00z\xeb\xff\xc1\x00\xee\x00\x00\x8e\xd4\x83q\xcf\x83\xff\x8f\x00F\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01^Fi\x99\x00\x00\xd8\'\xfev\x00\x19\x99\xa5.\x85b\x87\xec\xec[v\xff\x90\x00\x85<\x00\xff\x00\x00m\xbf\xf9\xc6\xa4\x00\x85\x19\xa3\x830\x9b\xff,\x18-\xc8\xff\xbc\x94\x05\x00H\x00\\\xb4\x8a,\xe6\xc5\x95\xff-\xa9\x0fNd~\xc4\xff\xfa\xffv\x94\x00\xa1F\xa8\xde$\xff\xff\xff\xbd\xc3\xee\xbd\xbd\x00d\xfd\x00\xff\x9a\xff\x8f\x00f\x00\x00\x98\x00\xff\x1ai\xd3\x8e\x00\xcd\xdcaB\xce\xcf9\xfff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\xd8HD\xed(j\xb6\xdc)\xe3\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf5]\xeej\nm\n\x1e\n\x12start_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00HB\n\x10\n\x06labels\x12\x06\x1a\x04\n\x02\xd1\x02\n\x1c\n\x10end_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00pB\n\x1b\n\x08video_id\x12\x0f\n\r\n\x0bUULJiM0Wefo\x12\xf1\n\n\xee\n\n\x0faudio_embedding\x12\xda\n\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01e\xf6O\x00\xb7\x00V\xab\xd5\x12\x95\xa5\x00\xbf\xff\xcf_\x9eB"\xff\xcd\xff\xb67\xff\xff\xa9\xaehkREv\xb9\x00\xa0\xb2\xb9\x9f\xc0\x92T\x00\xbdC!u\xd2\x00\x00\xff\xe83\x81\x18\x9e\x9d\x08\xa8\x00\x00>\xac\xffL6G\xf0\x00u\x00\xb9?\xff1O\x981N\xdd\xff\xff\xf3\xfd\xb7\xec\x8e\xff\xa44\x86\xce\xff\x95\x8f\x00\xab\x00\xa1\x00R\xff\x81\xff\x00\xd02i!\xffk\x00v\x00\x00\x83P\xff\xe0\xe0\xd3\x00\x9eZgk\xa9\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x1e\xff\x00\x00\x9d>\x98\xbc\xc0\x1c\x80\xbf\x00\xe1\xff\xb0!\xe2\x93%\xff\xca\xffa\x00\xff\xa9\xc7\x00\x98\xa1\x00/\xcf<\x00G\xff\xc7&\xa0\x96c\x00\xa9\x04\x10\x93\xff\x00\xa5\xed\x8d\x00M]\xa8s\x00]\x00\x1f\x00\xfa\xfap\x14G\xce\x00w\x19\xb3\x11\xa6+\xc9\xff(k\xff\xfe\xd5\xd1\xffX\xef\xb0\xff\xff\xff\xa9\x97\xff\xff`?\xff\x00\x00\x92l\x9dh\xff\x8e?G\xdc\xe7\xe0\x00\xe4\xc4\x00\xff\xc4\x00\xba\xb7\xda\xa2\x00\x00\x86\x8c(\xcb\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x00\xff\x00\x00\x97n\xa6\xb0\xb9&o\xff\x1e\xff\xff\xf5\x00\xff~$\xf7\xff\xffX\x00\xff\x84\x9e\x00\x8d\xff\x00\x1b\xff0\x00\x00\xff\xaaTj\x8e]\x00\x93\x00n\x97\xff\xa1\xbd\xffr\x00\x17\xff\xb0L\x00N\x00\x0b\x00\xd7P\xc8V\xcf\xf5\x07~\x7fO\x00\xa6]\xf5\xfa\x00\xa3\xc6\xff\x94\xff\xff\x8f\xff\xdc\xff\xff\xff\xb4\xf6\xff\xff\x956\xff\xb0-\xe8dv\xff\xffV\x0f\x9a\xaa\xffr\t\xff\xff]\xfd\xff\x00Vf\xadz\x00\x00\xcc\xf5\x12\xb2\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x00\xff\x00\x00\xabq\xaa\xaa\x90\x11n\xcc\x10\xd9\xff\xc53\xe7P\x0e\xf9\xff\xffx\x00\xff\x95\xca\x0c\xd6\xcf\x00\x00\x9cD\x00k\xff\xa1p\xbeS"\x00R\x00\xa5U\xff\xb9\x98\xed\x86\x007\xb5\x8a#\x0fy*D6\xecz\xad\n\xe4\xc9\x00b\x9c\xff\x00\xfb\xff\xd5\xff\x88ko\xd9]\xff\xffO\xcd\xa4\xff\xff\xd1~\xe9\xff\xff\xcf5\xffy[\xd1\xadX\xec\xff@\x93S\xe7\xff\xab\x04\xff\xffC\xba\xff1\x00\xff\xfc\xff\x00f\xffw\xa0\xbd\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01S\xb5^\x00\xbf+az\x9a0e\xb5\x00\x9b\xff\xc0Q\xb4fn\xcb\xbe\xe9\x949\xff\xab\xcc\xa2GW\x04t\x8c\xd5\x00\xd5\xdd\x88|\xf2\x83\x87\x14\x86>Nm\xe7\x105\xd3\xc1cA?\x87\xa0\x1fO0\x00\xae\xbd\xff?\x17n\xb0\x00M\x00b\x18\xfbSC|\x92\x87{\xff\x95\xfaw3\xba.\x7f\xf54\xb4e\xffp\x00\x00\xe68,\xc9\xa3o;\xd2\x00`\xd9ta\xff\x88aZM\x00MG\xc9\xc0\xd9\xf8\x00\xf6ue\x96\xdb\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x02\xfb;\x00\x9a\xad\x8f\xb9\x99/*\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff]J\xfc\x89\xffG\x00\xff\xf9\xff\xecq\xa5\x00c\xff\x00\x00\x18\xff^:g\xe02\x00\xff\x00\x98w\xa7lC\xff\xffbC\xbez\xfbPj\x00:\x00\xff\xff\xff\xfc\xe5\xf8*\xf4\xba\x07\x00@t\xffi{_\x87\xff\x00\x89\xdb\xb8\xe6\xf9\xc9\xff\xda\x00\x00\xffT]\x00\xff\xff\xc0\xc4=\xd8\xff\xff\xc7\x00\xffcr\xff\xa2^\x86\x9d\x00\xd5Z\x00\xff\xff\xf1+\xc4\xe0\x00\xa6\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01M\xb8E\x00\xb7(\x85\x8c\xa19\x8d\xe1\x00\xd9\xff\xc7\x0b\xc3@P\xcc\xfc\xffI\x00\xff\x9e\xac\x9dX\xb5/m\xb2\x85\x00Z\xa2s\xa1\x8ehG\x00^.L\x83\x9c|6\xa1\xd3\x97-|q\x8a\x00=\x00\x00O\xc8\xce`k)\x8d\tp\x18s\x17\x8b.\xba\xb2\xb3bu\xf9U\xd1x\x82\xabt~\xf7T\xab(\xff\xa4x\x00\xbdfp\xce\xa9\xb0x\xff\x00I\xd0\xb3\x94\xff\x8dD\x00\x1a\x00\x1eCd\xff\xff\x8b\x00{\'<\x00\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01:\xbc7\x00\xaa$\x8br\xac\'\x95\xbe\x10\xbe\xff\xa1E\xc0G~\xff\xf8\xffP\x00\xff\x9f\x9e\xaf\x83\xaa\x19i\x8d\xa7\x00\xad\x96\x8c\x94\xadwN\x13\x14!\x8a\x9f\xb1>i\xe4\xa9\x9bX}by\x126(B\x00\xe1\xc8\xbc\x0bP^Rt\xacU\x00\xffu\xbd\xbe\xffs\x19\xa8\rq\x83\xb5\x80|\x98\xae\xd1\xfbK\xca\xc5z\x00\xdbe\xca\xb7\xdb{Y\xff\x00\x00\xb5\xff\x99\xd4|Qk\xb1\x00\x135Z\xff\xff\xb6\x00C\x07\xff\x00\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x00\xf8>\x00\xc7\x82\xc4\xbe\xe5Gh\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x12\x00\xff\xd6\xffo\x00\xff\x96\x93R\x8a\xbd\x0f~\xed\xc7\x00\x00\xec\x94\x9aM\xb5)\x00\xd6\x00\x81\xc8UWV\xe1}\xf0b\xff\x13\xc8\xb5Z\x00@\x00\x92\xb8\x912\x9c\xdfI\xbc\xf67\x00\x85L\xff\xbd(E\xf1\xba/s\xf3\xba\xce\xff\x9e\xff\xffh\xbf\xff\xff\xc1\x00\xdf\x95\x95d\xb5\xb4\xff\xff\x16\x1c\xff\xff\x8e\x04/\x90\xffs\x16\x15\x00S\xb9\xd3\x93\x00\x00\x0b{\x00\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x00\xceN\x00\xc8Y\xa6\x84\xa3_\x9a\xed\x02\xd9\xff\xbe\x00\xba,\x00\xfe\xad\xff\x88\x00\xff\xd5\xb1vs\xd7Q\xa0\xd9[\tv\xb2\x93\x95f\xaf\x89g\xd4\x00\x81dN(OYY\xd1K\\\x00d\xad\x91\x00\x06V\xfd\xffGd\xffK\x1eg\xff\xff\x00\xddC\xdf\xa3H\xb1\x9e\xa7\xa3MD\xab\xd9\xff\xf3\xff\x8cm\xd5\xf3\xff\xc7\x83\xab\xc2\xc1\xd4\xff\xef\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xc8Eq.\x00\xad\xff\x00\x00M\x00\xff\xa6,\x9e\x90\x00Fo\xf9\xad\xb6\x81\xae\xe6\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x8e\x82\xd9\np\n\x1b\n\x08video_id\x12\x0f\n\r\n\x0bUUeLFaJl_88\n\x1e\n\x12start_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xc3C\n\x13\n\x06labels\x12\t\x1a\x07\n\x05~\x81\x01\x83\x01\n\x1c\n\x10end_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xc8C\x12\xf1\n\n\xee\n\n\x0faudio_embedding\x12\xda\n\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\n\xadz\x0f\x17|\xff\xbf\xff\xa5\x1a\xff\xbf\xc1\x03\x83\xff\x00~\xe7\xff\x00\xe1l\xb2.\x8e\xd2\xff\xed\x00\x00oT\xa5\xff5A\xff\xb8\xd6$\x00\xef\xff\xff\xff\x00\xc0S\xaeu\xf7\x00f\x00\x00\xbd\xadk[\xff\xf8\x00\xbf\x00\xff\x80\xff\x00\xfe\x1f\x03\xfc\xbe\xc4\xca\xcc\xf3\xfc\x0f\x1e\x9f`N\x00\xc2\xe4\x8f\xff\xee\xdcE\xff\xe7\x00\xff\xff\x00\xd0\x00\xa7Wt\xc6\x00\x00\x90s\x04\x01\xf6\xff\xec\x00\xfa\xa8\x00\x00\x00\xe2G\x00\xff*\x13sg\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x0b\x8e\x840\x84\x87\xff`\xed\xea\x1b\xff\xff\xf7\x00\x95\xec\r`\xee\xe9JG\xa7\xbaMjl\xb4\xd8C\x15\x00gv\xffQE\xb76\xa3}"\x9fzl\xfft\xc8\x00xP\x86\x00\xc3\x00\xc1xl}s_\xac\x00n\x03\x81\xda\xa2U\xf1\xa2\x00\xf4\x95\x99\xa8\xc7\x1b-g47\xe6<p\xa6\x90\xa8\xff\xfd\xfe\x89\xb9\x03\'\xff\xff\x04\xd5\x86\xab\xbe2\xdd#B\x95\xdf\xb7K\xadR\xda\x00\x92\xcb\x05K\x91\xff\x85\x00YUt\xe0\x92\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x18\x89\x8f\x12b\x8c\xe8\x9f\xff\xab\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00~\x977\xe0\x9f\xc5\x1c,\xa2\xad\x81\x92\x82\xe1&\x00$x\x11\x99\xfe\x00\x88\xff\x00\x00\xc4:\x8aqn\xffD\x00\xf7\xdci\xffK\xff\xb7>\xff\xd6\xff\x807\x16\x00\xd2\x00\x8b\xfd\xb4\x07\xc5\xe8\x00\x82\xff%\xf7\x1d\xff\xe1\x00\t\x00\xff\xff\x92\xffo\x00\x00\xea\x00\x00\xdc=\x10y\xfe}\xffC\xb9Gw\xff\xb5\x00PG\xff\xff\xff\xf4\x00\x14\xff\xffVSN\xccSLQ\xffe\x96\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01Mg\xaa1\xb4\x90qb\xdf\xab2\xa3\x90\xb52cb\x00\xa8\xa5\\~\x93z{\x87V\x00\xa2aI\xc3\xd0}(\xb5\x1b\xe1)9\x00\xe91Q<\xa7\xb0\xd7\x8aNnY\xffkw\xeal\xb1\xff\x006\xff\xc5\xa3F\xff\xf9\xffh\r\xd6~\x81\x8a\xf8\x00u&\xc5\x9dv\x01Y\x19\x00\x00F]\x00\x00\xc8\xd4*\x86m\xf5$\xff\xcb\x9fa\xccL\x9e\x005T\xaa\x00\xff\xb1\x00\x00"+\xc1\xab\x91\x00\x00\xd7\x13\xd0\x14\xff\x00~<\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01)\xc3\x82\x00B\x92\xff\xbc\xff\xe8\x00\xff\xff\xb9\x00\xb8\xfb\x00\x81\xa6\xff\x00\xff{\x82\x17\x8e\xdc\xd0\xd5\x00\rtU\xff\xff\x00D\xffW\xff\x00\x00\xff)\xa9\xff\x00\x83.\xc3\xff\x9b;\x1c\x00\xab\xff\xff\xbes\xff\xff\x000\x00\xffm\xff\x00\xdcG\x00\xfe\xce\xdey\xffY\xda\x94\xff\x81\x00^\x00\x94\xd4\xb1\xff\xff\xad\x00\xf5=\x00\x84\xffa\xff\x00\xe8\x13\xfe\x00\xff\x0e\xc4Lg&\xa6\x96\xff\x00\x00\xffs\x00+\xff\xda\x00#\xa2\xca\x00\xbc\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x7fR\x9ce\xa2F\xdek\xce\xaawo\xa5\xe0dD\xc8{\x89\xac\xad\x1fbU\x86\xa4\x88\xc3\xe6\xb2\x00\x00\xc5D\x97\xbfl\xac\x85\x97\xce\x86%\x8a\x88\xbf\x93\x003\x86\x9a\xd6\xd3\x02\xaej:\xce\x10\xff\xfff\x00\x00\xff_iv\xa0\xbcA\xd8\x92\xe2\xc5\xd6~\xe6\xff\xa8\x00\x00\xdb~\xb2l\x9a|\x10\x93\xe1\xb7\x89\x90B\xffm\x00\x00\xf1e\xa0\x1f5\xdb\x1b\x00\x88\xb2T\x88\x16\x06\xff\xa2b\xadu\x14\x86\xff\x00tZ\xa5@}\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01Fs\x8cY\x94]\xe4E\xff\x87\x10b\xdf\xda\x00\x14\xac\x13\xd5\xed\xbc\x1f{2T\xceKI\xd2D\x00\x0b\xfbg\xa2\xb0\x00`>\x86+\xddRREehs{"\x89S\xae\x00\x9d\xe7\x08\xb2\x83\xbd\x86P*\x00\xc4\x125}\x00\xe6\\\xc7m\xd5\xff?\xab\x00\xb5\xa5\x009\x90\x8c\xff\xf1\xf7\x8f\x9c[\xf0\xdd#\xa7r\xff\x85sb\xbe\x1a\xef.W\xc8$\x17\xaf\x8c\xb7sx+\xa1`\xc2\xb2\x80)\xab\xe4\'.\x00\xff\xb9\xa5\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01(\xb5\x81\x129\x9c\xff\x8b\xff\xc6\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x92\xda\x00\xac\xb0\xff\x1c\xffu\xa1L\xad\xb4\xfff\x00\x00\x9cT\xe0\xff\x00\x8d\xea\x14\xf8\x11\x00\xffT\x82\xff\x14\xa6\xb8|L\xb0\x00W0\xa9\xff\xff\xfdR\x97\xff\x00\xa5\x00\xff\xff\xff:\xa8G\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x05\xfb\x07\xf6Q\xc3\xad\x00\xdc\xff\xc9\xff\xbe\xe3\x00\xc7c\x00\xdb\xa1q\xff\x00\xf9\'\xff\x18[\x00\xccq5@\xef\xac\xf8\x0f\x00\xff\x0f\x00\x00\xffE\x00G\xe3h\x00X\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01<\xa8(\x1a\xb0\x91\xd3_\xc87j\x00\x1b\xc1\x00\x017l\xdd\xb7\x82\x00\xaf\x00\'\xc7\x00\x00\xff\xc4\x00\x00\xffd\x83\xa0n\xdaa\xff5\xc4\xba\xffc\x8c\xff\x00\x00\xa8\x00L\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\xa5\xa8\xd9\xdf\x13\xc6)\xf0\xa0\x00\xbc\x00a\xb7\x97\x1d\xf6\xffX\xc1,Cg\x00\x85\xa5\x00\xff\xffV\xf5\xff\x00\xee\xf1\xdf\x00\xff\xfc\xa4\xff|\xff\xfa\xa8\x15\xff\xd3S\x00\xeb\x00\x00\x9f\xf3\x10]\xff\x94vd\xb1E\xffan\x00\xff\xab;\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01+\xa7\x86d\xe0\x7f\xe7\x9e\xff\x98G\xbb\xff\xdb\x006\xdb\x04\xad\xb4\xb4T\x1fa\xa7uFA\x17^F\x00\xffklJ-\xd0\x13^:\xff\x85\x00\x82\xc3\x88\xd3\xb5\x00\x95\x91\xffj\xff\xbc\x00\x1b<\xdb`\x19o\x00\xd5\xd6H\xec\x1f\x8f\x14K#\xff\xf8F\xbe^\xe5\xae\x00\x00\xc6A\xaf/\x9c\x00\x00p\xff\xd2G\x99\x00\xcfV\x81\x00\xff\x00\xff\x8e\x80\xa2\x0b\x0b\x0b\x99\xa3\xff\xa5b\x8b`\x12d\xb80:\xff\x10\xd4\x00\xdf\x11\xcc\xff\xe8\x11Zi\xed\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00y|\x1b\xd4\nw\n\x1b\n\x08video_id\x12\x0f\n\r\n\x0bUUJ1DNycpiQ\n\x1e\n\x12start_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xf0A\n\x1a\n\x06labels\x12\x10\x1a\x0e\n\x0c\x89\x01\xec\x01\xf0\x01\xf4\x01\xf5\x01\x92\x02\n\x1c\n\x10end_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00 B\x12\xf1\n\n\xee\n\n\x0faudio_embedding\x12\xda\n\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xbch+\xb1}\xd4; \x93\xa3\xffy_\x97cR\xb1\x9brb\xff\x99us\xa4\xc8\x99\x00\xc7\x1c\x8att\x19\x92\xb9\x9d\xe6A]\x8a\xa2\xe4\x9a\x9eu\x93a\xb7\xd7\xd2y\x99\x1f\xa8\xc2\x98\xb0\xa1A\x82\x1b\x9c9fL\x96\xc4\x04\xb2c\x81)\x85m\x89{Td\xcda\x85\xcf\xb7Ny\x1f\xf3\x97\xa2\x9e\x91T\x00\x88\xe8\x9epf\x8f\xc2\xc0\x00:\xba\x9db\x90\xff\x0f(W\xc0\xa6x\xbex\xab\x1cj\xfd^\x00\x99\xa1lA\xbf\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xcb\xb4\x00\xaab\xffG+\xd6v\xff^R\xb8]q\xee\xffB\x1f\xffDe=\xcb\xd7\xb9\x00\xca\x00\x9f\xa1\x9a9d\xdb\xa4\xff\xc6XUJ\xff\x88\xffN\xc2~\xe1\xff\xf2z\xa7"\xda\xff2\xbe\xb0\x1b\x1fE\xce\x00EG5\xa4\x00\x91\x1a\xdb\x00\xd7\xffIrW\xa5\x002\xffo\xf8\xffxC\xc4\xfc\xc1\xec\x14\nE\x8cq\xff\xde\x00\xb6\xdd\xff\t\xff\xcd\x15\xcf\xdd\xff\x00\x85\x00\xf5\x9dQEcWUU\xd4L\x00\x9b\xa4\xcf\xce\xd1\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xd0\xa6\x00\x93n\xffN\r\xce\xc7\xffab\xfcc\x8d\xc4\xffP\x0b\xff\x85!\x00q\xbd\xf1W\xe4\x00\xd7\xb2\xb2d\\\xff\xaf\xf7\xff\x0c&\\\xff5\xffO\xdaz\xe7\xd6\xff\x93\xaca\xff\xb8A\x95S(\x0f\x82\x9a"/P\x00\x97,\xa0\x00\xffH\xff\xffN\x00\x83\xffF\x8d\xfa_\xff\xdd\xff?\xd4\xdd\xdb\x00\x00c\xff4\x00\x83\xff\x00\x81i\xff\x0f\xb6\x9e\x00e\xff\xff\x00\x96\x00\xc5\xd3\x93 \xffz\xff\x8f\xda\xfeQk\x90\xb4\x94\xdc\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xd2\x8a\x18\x82\x8e\xffR<\xc1\x9e\xff\x8cj\xd9]|\xb8\xec\x84+\xff\xba0\x1aN\xf1\xbdi\xff\x00\xd4\xab\x8a\x1e\x84\xfe\xcf\xe3\xff5W\xc0\xffv\xff\x9a\xee\xc6\xff\x82\xff\xda\xb1m\xff\xd2C\x93w\x00\x00\x89\xe7&V\x00`\xffF\xa4;\xff\x00\xff\xda\x8b"^\x98\xa9\x91s\x98\xc9\xdb\xff\xb3\xea\x96\xf2`P`z,R\x15\xff\x80\xa2\xb8\xe5)\x80\xf3M\x1e\xff\x9d\x00\xc6+\xc4\x9b\x00\x00\xac\xcd\xff\xc6\xb5\xffa]\xa6\xb4R\xce\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xce\x9a\x02\x95g\xff[\x00\xda\xfe\xffph\xffkh\xa3\xff\xc3\x1d\xff\xb2\x01\x002\xd4\xe4\x13\xff\x00\xff\xff\xc7Gq\xff\xc6\xff\xfe\x00?e\xff\x1a\xffZ\xffD\xcf\xff\xff\xae\xd1\x95\xff\xf7:\xe2:\x00\x00\xc3\xff\x00\x00\x00\x15\xca"\xb8O\xff7\xff\xff\x00\x00\xad\xdea\xf9\xab\x00\xff\xff\xff\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\xe1\x96\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00D2\xff\x00(\xfe\x11a\xff\xff\x00\xff\x00\xd8\x88\x19\x00\xff\xb1\xff\xdb\xff\xff2Q\xbdN\x91\xb9\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xc1\xbf\x00\x8cP\xffZ@\xd9\x97\xff\xab2\xe6R\x84\xda\xff|\x00\xffk#)\xb7\xf2\x90\x0e\xff\x00\xff\xa3\xcf\x18G\xff\xba\xff\xff\x069v\xff*\xff\xae\xff\xa1\xff\xff\xffuy\x00\xff\xffq\xe7\xed\x00\x004\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\xea\x00\xbc\x00\xff\x19\xff\xff\x02\x1et\xf3%\xc0\xa9\xc0\xff\xff{\xff\xb4\xff\xf5a\x00\x86\x07\x83\x00\x84\xff\x00[\x8c\xff\x1f\xff\xff\x00Z\xff\xff\x00\xff\x00\xf0\xa3\x00\x00\xbc\xc3\xe6\xff\x89\xf1\x00\xb9+\xff\x00\xdb\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xce\x9c\r\xac\x84\xdbZ\x1c\xdaz\xd6;H\xabcl\xba\xe1Q\x1c\xff2P=\xc1\xb8\x93\x0e\x8e\x06\x86\xb0m\x82s\xbb\xa0\xae\xbe\x18lc\xcf}\xe1P\xa5R\x8a\xff\xb3X\\I\xd0\xb2c\x93dRFjlCL`\x15&\x03bO\x7f[\xff\xff-gt\x9d@\x99\xb8:\xbd\xa2:]\xa1\x94\xa4\xae\x1cm~_?\xdd\xd8\x04\xb3\xcd\xa7[\xff{\x07\xe3\xff\xd3t\xec\x00\x83\x89fh!r\x8a!\xa8G\x00{Y\xbb\xca\x97\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xcf\x901\xae\x89\xd6F0\xc3\xe2\xc6cU\xb8eO\xbb\xd3\xaa>\xff\x7ff\x00\x8f\xcc\x97$\xb7S\x82\xcc\x8cs\x84\xff\xad\xcdjUh\x8b\xe5z\xb47\x9e_k\x96\xe5\x81\x8e{\xc3\x8er\xdb<\x9c+S\x96\x00\x00\x8a1{:\xbd\x89lI\x87\xff\x7f\x00\xcc9\xbdKPu\x9b\x16\x91\x98\xbe\xa1\xe9D\xc4\xfc3\xe8\xf0\x92\x00F\x92\xd7y!\xc75\x9d\xd3\xa5\xff\x00\x95%\xff]I\xeb_\xe6\x00\xa1\xff-[\xffw\x02\x82\xde\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xc5X=\x93\xa8\xa0B?\xbe\x8d\xdbAa\x99nD\xae\xdalW\xe2\x9dW-z\xae\x90G|_\xb5\x8aon\x87\xbd\x91|\x9bay\x80\xa1\xa9V\x8ay\x8c\x89\xaa\xden\x8fdnvj\x84s\xa5ydyOf\x9e4@r\x9c^\x8cL\xb7\xb7Pc\x94\x95\x96Jek\x9bYeK\xec\x9f\x95Zro\x9fZ\xd0\xa7\x80Cn\xeewc\x95:{w\x9b\xdax\x8a\x9b\x84\xa5n\xeeE\xa9VK\xe6\x84"\x86\xec3Cq\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\xc6T[\x93\xa9\xb5C:\xa0\xa8\xef\x8eh\x8fq4\xb3\xa3bq\xad\xa7V>n\xcd\xadT\xa2Yn\x9f\x8fS\xb1\x8d\xa3\xb0pY\x85\xca\xa9\xa1\x94q\x81\x80\x83\x95\x91\x95x\x9c\x8e\x81nqbx\xaap>eo\x86\xcf\x8an\x7f\xa4\xc5<\xa3\x86\xbdW\x9c\x83\xaex\xb1\xc9i\x9e\xa1E\xd4\x85\xb3\x81\xeb0\x981\x8f}\xa3_~\xbc\x92{1\x9f\x90\x9e\x98\xa7\x8c\x9b\xb1\x8a\xa9\x8e\xb2f\xdcdj\xafz`u\x9c\x0f\xa0\x00\xea\xe6C\x8f\xe6\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x8e\x82\xd9\np\n\x1e\n\x12start_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xf0B\n\x13\n\x06labels\x12\t\x1a\x07\n\x05~\x81\x01\x83\x01\n\x1c\n\x10end_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\x02C\n\x1b\n\x08video_id\x12\x0f\n\r\n\x0bUUoEKp0yqLY\x12\xf1\n\n\xee\n\n\x0faudio_embedding\x12\xda\n\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01#f\x84\x0eu\x92\'\x90\xd6X\x89\x7f\x84\xf0\xff}\x14\xce\x8c\xff\xdd\x00\x00p~\xff\xff\x89D\x1e\x00l\xff\x00q\x00\xfe\x19\xff\xae\x06\xff\xbaUE\xf6\xc4(d9\xff\x00v3\xff\x00\x00\xff*\xff\xff\x00\x00t\xd1\xc7\x86o\x00N\xc4\xffe\xff%\x00\x84@\xff\x00\x00\x00.\x00i\xff\xff\x00\x00\x03\x00\x15W+\x00\xff\x00\xcdb\xff\x94\xff/\x0c\xffF\x00\x98x\xff\xff\xff\xdc\x00\xde\xff\xff\xff\x00(>\x00nT_\xff\x10J\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x0fp|\x13I\xc0V\xa2\xfft9\xdc\xe9\xff\xa8\x8cJ\xff\xdd\xff\xb1\x00\x00\x8c\x90\xff\xff\xac\xb6\x00\x00`\xfd\x003\x00nZ\xff\x9e\x00\xff\x9f\x00!l\xff\xde\x00\xff\xff\x00r9\xff\x00\x00\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x9c\xb8\x8b\xb8\x00\x7f\xff\xffV\xe6\xdb\x00@"\xff\x85\x00\x00\xa2\x18\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\xff\x00\xbc\x10\xffs\xffL\x00\xff\x00\x00\xffc\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00(\xff\xff\xde;\xa8\x00\x00\x00\xb0\x00\xff\x00I\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x00\x8f\x7f\x00\x89\x9b\xb9\xa8\xf0\x98+\xe5\xfb\xd8$\x89\xbe\xb5w\xff\xff\x00 \x9c\xe9\x94\xbc\x8b\xc46\x00!\x94#\x9a7\xd3r\xffu\x8e\xff\\*Fn~\xe7\xb6z\xff\x178\xbb\xff\x009\xadR\xff\x86\x00\x00\x00K\x85V\xff\x89\xa5\xd6\xff\x91<\xb7\xaexX\xff\x99\x00\x00\x11m~\xc1\xa4k\x00\xa1\x0fz\xff\x1f\x06\xff\x7f\xff\x00\xff\xa8\xa3D\x0b\xff\x14\x87a\xa6\xff\xff\xc7q\x17\x00\xff\xe7\xadM\xff\x15\x81\xb1\xa1X\xd2\x06\x87\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x00\xad\x84\x00e\xd1\xbc\x93\xff\x88\n\xfb\xff\xffN\xb5\x90\xff\xc8\xff\xe7\x01\x00\xc0\xf1\xd7\xb2\xb4\xb0\x00\x00H\x8f\x00\xc4\x00u\xa9\xffr\x00\xff\x92\x00\x00*\xad\xbc\x00\xc3\xff\x00\xffC\xff)\x00\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xbd\x94\x00\xff#\xff\xfb\xffHO\xff\x00\xc4\x15\xff\xfb\x00\x00\x9eo\xeb\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\xff\x00#\xffx\xff\x1c\xff\xc9\xff\t\x00\xff\x00\x00\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\xc0\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x00r\xff\xc3\xc5\xff\x00\xcf\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01E;\x89#\xa0w4\x80\xb9\x8bu\x7f\xc3\xa1\x85klmY\xd6\xb2\x1fGd\xae\xa8\xde=yq3\x8aqepA\xccf\x8a\xc6\x81\x88\x99hwfi\x99\xc0n\x90t1|u\x047\x86\x9ex\xfd\xaeOz\x86\xda\xc7\x83Hf\xaa\xc6\xffq\x0b\x99,Yp\x90\x9a.\xb5*\x80\xc0\x9e\x9b%f\x17\x99\xfbr\x00\xb5O-8\xba\x90f\xc6J\xd8ZS2\xac\xff\xf11\xed\x8c:\xb0\xff\xb7\xb6Q\x00i\x1b\x80\x08\x9b\x87\xa0\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x013xf\x10\xe2l\x9c\x96\xd5~V\x9f\xd7\xcf\x1bX\xba\xb6A\xfa\xb86\x84I\xa0h\xebh=\x02n+4\xc2v\x00\x80\xbb\xa7\xff\x82\xcbx\x00\'\x00w\x84\xf0X\xb1\x8ev\xff\xd9l\x00\x8b\x80\xdd\xb4zy\x00\x00\xff\x00\xb38\x9b\xe5\xff\xff\x05\xff\xff\x00KY\xa7z\x80\xa3\rR\xd6\xf2\x9a\x00\xe62\xbe\xf8,\x00\xffI\x00\x92\x9e\x8e\xff7\x00\xf4\x008\xaa\xe4\xff\x11b\xffpc\xc7\xfe\x92\xff\xc0\x00[J\'\x00\xff\x05\xb3\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x010@\x87,\xb3\x87Hz\xb0z>y\xb6\xabG\x90\xa0r1\xf9\x97:c\x0c\xb9\x9a\xda{\x95>\xa3\x88hZ|(\x87d_\xa2a\x97\x93I>\x82v\x8d\xb2\x9c\xdfksN\x8aF(K\x90\xe7\x90S\xa7&:\xef\x9a\x95X\xc4\x96\x9f\xbadr\xb7H\x93.\xbe\x96\x86\x9a\x0e\x8e\x9f\x9e\xb3<PW\xa4\xdbpIKD\x16G\xb4\xb0\xb1\x80\x08\xd3\x86\x8f\x90\xfa\xff\xea\x8b[\xc6`\x88\x89\xb6\xe7uG\xb6\x01\x00T\xd6t:\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x01|\x87[\xdb}\xc7\x94J\xa5I\x9d\xd3\x7f\x00\xc4\xd6\xd82\x98\x8dwa\x00\xffO\xbf\xaf[<\x94y\x1dsHp\x82\x1a\x8b{\xab\xc4\x8f\x17\x01:-\xab\xffpv\x0c\x00\x00\x86\xc1\x87*\x8f\xa2.+8\\\x95\xbcy-\x03\xff\xa1fp@\x803e\xb3\x1c\x84\xebv\x9f\xa1\x8a\xf7Y\xde\x9d\xdb\x04\xbf\xff\xff\x97\xf1\xe6\x80\x00\x00qag]\xdf_<\xff\xc5\xac\xb0_L\xdbz;\xc4\xcd\xd1\xbc\x9epJ\x8f6\xb09`\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x00\x8evY\xf5\x90\xaf\x8aF\xb7O\x9f\xd5\x86\x00\xb4\xff\xc7T\xbft{D\x00\xed5\x94\xb9dg\x90T^@A\x15\xd2m\x81k\x9e\x98\xbc\x00\x00o\xb5\xf4\xf6s\x9cK\x00\x00\xc8\xb7\xb5\x00\x81\xd2\r\x00\x00\x83\x98\xdf\x9chX\xff\xff\xe9\x85\x00\xca-e_\xa0x\x94W\x08\xae\xd9\x80\x87\xf3\x94\x89y\xb2\xff\x8d\xbe\xff\xed\x99Q\x16\xb5\xba6\xfb\xff\x91\xc6\xff=Z\xff\xba\x17\xbd:v\xff\xd3\xcbmJu\x7f\xff\x1f\x1fO\x92\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01!sqj\xf0[\xbbw>\xae\x81\x8d\xca}\x00\xa9\xaa\xec`LD\xbd8\x00\xff\x81\xd1\xe5\x84n\x7f\x80\x89IAE\xb66{M\xb17\xbb1\x00e\xbez\xfb\xaa\xbdC\x16\x00%\xe9d?\xb1\xc2U\x00(\xff\x9f\xf6\x1e\x00\nk\xca8\xa5\x84\xd9\x00b\xa6a\xcc\xd7\xbe3J\xfe\x88f\x8b\x9e\xffz\xa3\x98\x9b\x86\xffl\x92\xb8\x00\xd1\xc6\x00\xa1\xac\x8b1\xda\x00v\xff\x95\xad\xb32I\xbb\xb3\xbe\xc2+\x17F\xffP\x84\x89\xa7\x95\xff@x\xe3\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf5]\xeej\nm\n\x1b\n\x08video_id\x12\x0f\n\r\n\x0bUUuXfyfCaL4\n\x1e\n\x12start_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00*C\n\x10\n\x06labels\x12\x06\x1a\x04\n\x02\x00C\n\x1c\n\x10end_time_seconds\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x004C\x12\xf1\n\n\xee\n\n\x0faudio_embedding\x12\xda\n\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01:\xd1\xff\xe7\x1e\xb4\xff\x10p_\x00\x15\xa3\x00N\x00\x00\xea\x00\x90\xff\xa3\xff\xd9\x00\xff\x00\x13\x00J\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xda\x18\x00\xca\xb4\x00f\xff\xffD\xf1^\xcf\x00\xa2\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00^\xff\xff\xb9\x00\x00\xccJ\xff\x004 \x00\x00\xff^\xb5\xf3\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x00\x00Y\xff\x0f\x9a\xc5\x00\xe7q\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\'\x00\xff\xff\xff\xf4W\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\x00\xff\xff\xf5\xff\x00\x00\xff\xf8\xdc\x9a\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01i\x9d\xe7\xca\xa3W\xdcy\x99l%\x81\xb7\x00\x00\x1e7\xd8\x03[\x93\xe0\xf4K\x00\xff\x00&\x001\xb3\x00\x00\x00\xfd\x88\xc3\x00\x15sc\x00\xff\xc0uc\x07\xc1)W\xd4U\xffr\x00-5\xf0\xfffK\x92h\xff\x00\x9f\xff\xde\x00\x00\xff\x00\x83\xd1\x00\xdb\xce\xff\x10k\x00mA\xff\xff\xde\x00W?\x00\n{\xff\xff\x06\xff\x00F\xd5\xff~\xaf\xcd\x9f\xb9\x97\xff\x00\x9b\x00C\xffo\xff\x7f\xff\x9b\xb9f-t\xff\xcd\x15\x9f\x00p\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01l\xdf\xff\xcf8\x95\xdbPdqon\xcb\x00\x00\x00]\xff\x0fg\xffj\xe4\x8b\x00\xff\x00G\x00\x00|l\x00\x00\xdc3\xa9\x00,\x8c\x8b\x00\xff\xa7H>\xa6\x19\x006\x00\xc9\xffl\t;\x1f\xff\xc2\xaf\xa9}Y\xff\n\x94M\xd7\x00\x00L\x05\x1b\x00\x00\xff\xff\xeb\x00a\x00\x8f\xd2\xf0\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x004?\xaf\xff\xff\xdfE\x002"\xff\xc0\xa4w6X\x8d\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\xffa*\xff\x1eyJD\xa1\x00\xffZQ\x00\xb4\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01k\xd2\xff\xcb<\x97\xfflm\x80\x1do\xca\x00\x1d)]\xff\x00S\xff\x9a\x82k\x00\xfc\x00\x0e\x00\x00b~\x00\x00\xff:x\x00\x00\xda\xce\x00\xff\xbd\x00EvQ\x00\x02:|\xff\x8a?jH\xff\x8e\xae!\x14(\xa7\x00\xffQ\xbf\x00\x02\x85\x00^+\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\n\x00\xd6\xc2\xbd\xb4\x17.\x00\x00\x00\x00q\xff\xff\xcb\x00\x00Y\x00\xff\x9c\xd7L\xbc~s\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd6\xff\xff\x00\xff\xa9\xdd\x00+\x81\x00\xfff\xb4\x15\x8c\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01\x81\xa2\xfe\xb4\x97H\xbd\x88\x9a\x8aFd\x94\x00\x00na\xb63=\xa9\xe4P2\x00\xd8\x00\x0f\x1fJ\x8cx\x11O\xff\x9fs.#\x8cU\x00\\\xc35\xb60]\x00F\xafW\xff{C0+\xff\xb0\xe9FgK\xff\x00\xb4\xa9-\x00\x11|\x00\xee\xa2\x00\xc1\xff\xff+\x05\x00\xff\xf7?\xd0\xcd\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd5\xff\xc4*\xb9\x00\x00\x18\xff\xcf\xd6\x00\x92h\xff\xff\x00\x06\x00\x17\x85a\xd9.\xff\xff\xce\x01\x005\x01\x94\x06\xff\x00\x9b\xb7\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01c\xf3\xff\xbaWV\xf7\xc9q\x8b\x89\x83\xb6\x00\x00k[\xc3\x00\x81\xd7j[*\x1f\xff\x00\x00\x15:\xb0?\x14\x00\xffr\xe9\x00<\x82Y\x00\xb9\xec\x1b\xda\x13\x87\x00\x00\xbf\xab\xe9gY\x87\xff\xff\xff\xff+\x16 \xff\x18\xc4n\\\x00Pj\x00\x8e\xcd\x00\x85\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xb1kg\xf5\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\xba\xff\xff\x99(\xff\x00\x04\x00\xff\xce@\x00+\xdd\xa5\xdd\x00\x00\x00X\xb1\xa0\xffJ\xff\xfb.\xb3\x00mSU\x00\xd8\x00\xff\xc2\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01r\xf2\xff\xc6CK\xf7\xc3qp\x80\xaf\xca\x00\n(s\xfa\x00N\xccPnV\x00\xff\x00\x00C\x00|\xd3\x00-\xff{\xe0\x80\x10\x9e\xb0\x00\xcek\x10\xc220\x00\x00"\xa9\xe1\xa2|(}\xe0\xc7\xff\x0c\x00I\xff\x00\xb7I~\x00|\x00\x1f!\x14\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x84p\xff\x9b\x00\x00\x00\x002<\xff\xf1\xff\xc4\x00\\\x00\xff\xeep$Z\x13\xc5\xe1\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x89\xff\x00\xff\x80\xe1\x004\xd1\x00\xa4\x06\xac\x00\xff\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01^\xff\xff\xdd\r\x84\xff\xa5A\x90_\x98\xe6\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xff\x00\x91\xff\x00gz\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00{m\x0e\x00\xff}\xefq\x00\xa9~\x00\xc1\xd5+\x8e<\x00\x00\x00sC\xff\x91\xb1\x83\xfd\xff\xff\xe0\x00\x00Y\xff\x00\xcb\x00t\x00\x13+\x00\x82\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xf9^s\xff\x004\x00\x00\x14]\xb6\xff\xff\xffl\x00N\x00\xff\xbf\x87\x00L\x00#\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x87\xf6\xd9\xf3<\xff\x02\xa9W\x00\xb2\x00\x00\x1a`_\xff\xe2\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01g\xc2\xff\xaa\x83Q\xd3\xc9\x89\x9d\x8d\x99\xa4\x00\x08Py\xd7PB\xbb\x97Q\x82\x00\xab\x00\x007\x1ezm\x8e\'\xffU\xb3j+\xff\xa6\x00\x9f`r\xb6P_\x1a>rn\xff\xca\x81By\xaf\xc9\xffV\x17p\xff\x00\xff\xe0\x12\x00\x1f\x97\x00\xc9>\x00\xa6\xff\xff\x04\x11\x00\xda\x97d\xff)\x00\x00\x00\x13q\x8b\xff\xa7f\x8d\x00?\x00\xf0\xf6\xff\xc9\xa2\x00[\xff\x00\x0f\x00E+\xc3\xd8&\xd6p\xaf+;y\x10\x00\x00\x96N\xff\xff\n\x86\x01\n\x83\x01\n\x80\x01U\xe5\xff\xee\x00\xd7\xff$k\xdc\x0bm\xce\x00i\x00\xad\xe7\x00\xe9\xff1\xa0\xe6\x00\xeb\x00.\x00\x00\xb0H\x00\x00\xff\x00g\x00<0\x00\x00\xe4\xff\x00B\x9eu\x06\x00vi\xff\xb4\x00\x00\xd3\xff\xfft\x00\x00r\xa9Mw\x00e\x00\x14\xff\xbb\xb5\x0f\x04\xff\xff\xffN\x00\x00\xef\x02A\xff\x00D>\x00\xff\x00\xff\xff\xffb\x00\x00K\xff\xff\xff\x86\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xff\xd3\x00\x9b\x00\xff\xe5\x00/\xff\x86\x00\x006\xf6*\x00\xff\xff\x00X\xff@\x80\xe9A'
```

**What I tried**

- Decoding this to `utf-8`, `utf-16` or `ascii` did not help. I get the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

- Converting to `list`. This created a list of integer values, but I am unsure what to do with this.

Any assistance here would be appreciated

Comment: Direct link to the dataset `features.tar.gz` : 
storage.googleapis.com/us_audioset/youtube_corpus/v1/features/features.tar.gz